# Counting occurrences in Array

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I am counting the occurrence of each element in the array but I get the error "Value cannot be null" This doesn't make sense to me because arr1 is fully populated with no null values except the last 5 elements which are null.

Here is my code. I am using dictionary for the first time so I may have some logic error somewhere. I am reading from a textfile.

```
string[] arr1 = new string[200];
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("newWorkSheet.txt");
string Templine1 = "";
int counter = 0;
while (Templine1 != null)
{
    Templine1 = sr.ReadLine();
    arr1[counter] = Templine1;
    counter += 1;
}
sr.Close();

// Dictionary, key is number from the list and the associated value is the number of times the key is found
Dictionary<string, int> occurrences = new Dictionary<string, int>();
// Loop test data
foreach (string value in arr1)
{
    if (occurrences.ContainsKey(value)) // Check if we have found this key before
    {
        // Key exists. Add number of occurrences for this key by one
        occurrences[value]++;
    }
    else
    {
        // This is a new key so add it. Number 1 indicates that this key has been found one time
        occurrences.Add(value, 1);
    }
}

// Dump result
System.IO.StreamWriter sr2 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("OrganizedVersion.txt");
foreach (string key in occurrences.Keys)
{
    sr2.WriteLine("Integer " + key.ToString() + " was found " + occurrences[key].ToString() + " times");
}
sr2.Close();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Edit: I put all the code here including declaration.

Comment: Show the declaration and initialization of `arr1` and `counter`.

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly your question but Linq could reduce the number of lines here:

```
var groups = arr1.GroupBy(item => item);
foreach (var group in groups)
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} occurences of {1}", group.Count(), group.Key);
}
```

Comment: Yes Linq is the answer. Maybe you can add a variation with ToDictionary() as well.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, ToDictionary wouldn't work here as there are multiple items with the same key, ToLookup would work

Comment: You could use both to get a dictionary of counts, something like `.ToLookup(...).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Count())`. `GroupBy` would work in place of `ToLookup`, not sure right off if there's a difference in this instance.

Comment: @TimS., yes but if he only needs to get the number of occurences per string, the materialization is probably overkill.

Comment: @TimS. GroupBy allows the defferred execution, ToLookup creates a materialized collection

Comment: @vc74 Ah, that's it, thanks. If you're going to materialize it with `ToDictionary` immediately afterwards, I don't suppose it'll make much of a difference. For that matter, if you're going to do a simple `foreach` loop through the groups and print each line, it doesn't matter much if you materialize first.

Answer (score 1):

My money is on `arr1` being null (based on the fact that you should know the size beforehand but you're filling with lines from a file that could possibly change).  The good thing is that you don't actually need it.

Replace this:  `foreach (string value in arr1)`

... with this:

```
foreach(string value in File.ReadLines("fileName"))
{
}
```

[MSDN File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx)

Comment: omg! @Austin Salonen your solution worked!!! What kind of magical wand did you flick?

Comment: What is the reason this works 

                    foreach (string key in occurrences.Keys)
                    {
               
                       Console.WriteLine(key.ToString() +","+ occurrences[key].ToString() );
                    }

but if I do sr2.WriteLine and try to write the output to a file it only writes the last line to the textfile?

Comment: @Harmond:  You should pose that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

> "arr1 is fully populated with no null values"

Nope. The last item that you put in the array is null. Check the value before you put it in the array:

```
while (true) {
  Templine1 = sr.ReadLine();
  if (Templine1 == null) break;
  arr1[counter++] = Templine1;
}
```

Or if you like this method better:

```
while ((Templine1 = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
  arr1[counter++] = Templine1;
}
```

Now, loop up to the index `counter`, instead of looping through the entire array regardless of how many items you put in it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
  string value = arr1[i];
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Harmond: Have you changed the loop where you use the array?

Comment: I got it working without error using foreach File.ReadLines but now my output file is all empty...If I do Console.WriteLine it displays everything properly but if I write to file it shows blank in file...Something is up with my last foreach loop.

Comment: @Harmond: I would need to see the code to have a chance to tell what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you need to check if there is `null` in your value

```
foreach (string value in arr1)
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
     {
      ........
```

This will take care of problems you might have in the file.