# How to count options in array

Tags: c#

I have an array: options[15,12,52,a,12,15,abc,15] and I need to count options.

Example: 
counts[15]:3 or counts[12]:2 ...

I need this in C#. How can I do this?

**Thank you for your answers. My solution is here:**

```
Dictionary<object, int> counts = new Dictionary<object, int>();
for (var t = 0; t < voters_options.GetLength(0); t++) {
  if (voters_options[t] != null) {
    if (!counts.ContainsKey(voters_options[t]))
      counts[voters_options[t]] = 1;
    else
      counts[voters_options[t]] = 1 + counts[voters_options[t]];
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to do, what research have you done into how to solve this problem, and what problems have you run into with your research/attempted solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C# begginer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object[] options = { 15, 12, 52, "a", 12, 15, "abc", 15 };

            Dictionary<object, int> counts = new Dictionary<object, int>();

            for (var t = 0; t < options.GetLength(0); t++)
            {
                if (!counts.ContainsKey(options[t]))
                    counts[options[t]] = 1;
                else
                    counts[options[t]] = 1 + counts[options[t]];
            }

            foreach (var entry in counts)
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Key: " + entry.Key + "; Count: " + entry.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Results are:

```
Key: 15; Count: 3
Key: 12; Count: 2
Key: 52; Count: 1
Key: a; Count: 1
Key: abc; Count: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ grouping:

```
string[] options = { "15", "12", "52", "a", "12", "15", "abc", "15" };
var groupedOptions = options.GroupBy(o => o)
                            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
foreach (var groupedOption in groupedOptions)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", groupedOption.Key, groupedOption.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with linq in c#:

```
var groups = arr1.GroupBy(item => item);
foreach (var group in groups)
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} occurences of {1}", group.Count(), group.Key);
}
```

[Counting occurrences in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527810/counting-occurrences-in-array)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a traditional approach.

```
var options = new [] {"15","12","52","a","12","15","abc","15"};
Dictionary<string, int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(var t in options)
{
    if(counts.ContainsKey(t))
        counts[t]++;
    else
        counts[t] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to count the elements.

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> CountOptions(int[] options)
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> counts = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();
    for (var t = 0; t < options.Length; t++)
    {
        counts.AddOrUpdate(options[t].ToString(), 1, (k, v) => v + 1);
    }
    return counts;
}
```